# Preprocessing Latex: What is your workflow? Your tools?

Tags: macros, expansion, publishing

I know, for various reason, some users preprocess their latex file using `Perl` or `sed`, say.

I'm considering doing this to, so I would like to seek your guidance, to smooth my entry in this area.

My use case is a simple macro expansion preprocessing

```
If $\ep$ is small...   -->  If $\epsilon$ is small...
```

So that a compilation session becomes

```
doc.tex  --preprocessor-->  post.tex  --pdftex--> post.pdf
```

And the following issues arise

1. There is generally a mismatch between line numbers in `doc.tex` and `post.tex`. So that `pdftex` error messages points to a line in `post.tex`. But, really, one wants the line number in `doc.tex`.
2. The same for `synctex`. Backward and foward search are with respect to `post.tex`. But, one really wants them to be with respect to `doc.tex`.
3. Sometimes, one wants to go back and forth from `doc.tex` and `post.tex`. The `preprocessor` knows the corresponds between lines of the two documents. But then, how to put this knowledge in a workable way. I mean, text editors does not have out-of-the-box support for these backward-forward trips.

So, do you know some software, workflow or technics which will flatten (1)-(3)?

I look around, but I could only find example of `Perl` or `sed` preprocessing scripts.

I never saw the question of the workflow discuss somewhere.

**EDIT**

The line mismatch can originate from *big* expansion

```
A function is continuous if
    \multiline_continuity_definition_I_often_use
Hence ...
```

where the definition is expanded to

```
\begin{description}

   \item[Standard] 
        $\forall \epsilon ... $

    \item[Nonstandard]
        $x \approx y ... $

\end{description}
```

**Edit 2**

The point of this question is to discuss preprocessing technics.

My examples are very simplistic, but I hope they catch the main challenge of a preprocessing session.

Comment: What causes the line mismatch?  Are you hard-wrapping your lines so that `\ep` --> `\epsilon` causes 'hard' changes to lineation?  Soft-wrapping might be better in your case, unless it is something else causing the mismatch.

Comment: Even if the editor is hard-wrapping, the described preprocessor shouldn't move the line breaks.

Comment: Given that TeX is mostly a macro processing engine with some typesetting capabilities added, `My use case is a simple macro expansion preprocessing` must be the strangest use case for wanting to invoke an external processor. Why on earth can't you use `\def\eps{\epsilon}` ????

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It was not easy to write this question. I tried to catch the main points of a _preprocessing session_. It's true that my epsilon example is not so good.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton, perhaps but it seems that all three of your issues go away if you use TeX to do your re-processing so I think you'd need to give an example of something that can't so easily be done in TeX (there are examples: pulling fragments from a database, translating between different languages, ....)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh whoa! I'm a very average tex user. I've an interest in preprocessing technics people use, but I can't come with as good an example as you mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no full solution for this problem, as far as I know, because it will vary depending on your needs.

But here are two hints which should rule out your three problems for most cases:

### Use LaTeX as much as possible

Your first example could easily be solved by

```
\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}
```

and your second one by

```
\newcommand{\multiline_continuity_definition_I_often_use}{% You might prefer a shorter name :)
\begin{description}

   \item[Standard] 
        $\forall \epsilon ... $

    \item[Nonstandard]
        $x \approx y ... $

\end{description}
}
```

The key point is to avoid shadok logic, that is "Don't waste time developing a tool you don't really need". Even if the tool looks beautiful.

### Try to separate what is in the document and what isn't

This is for "real" examples where you need a preprocessor. Usually, that will be because they involve dynamic data (if you need to do always the exact same thing, latex should be enough) and difficult computations/processing.

What you can do then is separate this dynamic part from your document. For example, `\input` a file which will only contain the part which will need preprocessing.
Then preprocess the document (following these `\input`, or simply filtering the auxiliary files based on their extension, for example), and compile.

Latex can output the errors in a file-line-error style, and then the line-numbering won't be messed up. If you are using a multifile-aware editor (like, for example, `emacs + AUCTeX + refTeX`), this can be made almost transparently.

About synctex, it shouldn't cause any issue either. And for the back-and-forth between the base document and the processed one... Well, since you only change small auxiliary files, there should be no problem.

A good example of this workflow is the `sagetex` package. It allows users to make some computations with the symbolic computation software `sage`, and typeset their results directly in the `.pdf` document.

It uses some post-processing to make it even more transparent to the user, but the idea is the same:

1. The user inputs the computations in the `.tex` file (using a few commands)
2. A first run of `pdflatex` extracts all these `sage` bits in a `document.sage` file.
3. A run of `sage` on that file creates a `document.sageout` containing the results.
4. A second run of `pdflatex` inserts these results in the final document.

It is a fully-developed package, seriously optimised for user-friendliness, but you don't need such a carefully-designed solution. For example, you can create the extra files by hand (with the help of your editor, it can be as easy as typing `\input{filename}` and hitting a few keys).

And once again, this isn't a full solution, you will probably need some work to find out what really suits your needs... Take it as hints towards your workflow, nothing more.

Comment: +1 yes sagetex is a good example (rewriting sage in tex would be inconvenient:-)